# Angular-google-maps search-box

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I have this structure:

- myFolder

  - myApp.coffee
  - index.html
  - searchbox.tpl.html

And in myApp setting:

```
$scope.searchbox = {template: "searchbox.tpl.html"}
```

I'm using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087757/working-example-of-angular-google-maps-search-function?answertab=active#tab-top) but i got **TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchBox' of undefined**, what could be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `angular-google-maps` in two ways:

1) by including the API before `angular-google-maps`.
...In that case you need to include the library `places`, this way:

```
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=pt&v=3.17'></script>
                                                           ^
                                                        see? there
```

2) by using `.config` (recommended).
...In that case you need to include the library `places` this way:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        //    key: 'your api key',
        v: '3.20', //defaults to latest 3.X anyhow
        libraries: 'places,geometry,visualization' // <--- see? there
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Is necessary include **libraries=places**

```
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&language=pt&v=3.17'></script>
```